# insert a values in php

Tags: php, insert

I want to insert groupID to the db
this is my model

```
public function getgroupID()
{
    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
    $query = $this->db->query("select groupID from groups where member01ID='$username'");
    return $query->result();
}
```

this is my view

```
<?php foreach ($id as $row) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row->groupID . " '  >" . $row->groupID . " </option>";
} ?>
```

i can insert other values but i cant insert groupID.the problem is i dint know how to get groupID to insert(because groupID get from login information (in model))

Comment: Are you having the user submit a form, or is there some ajax call being fired when the user makes a selection, or what?

Comment: Where are you trying to insert *anything* into the database?  What's stopping you from inserting a record?